# GCC crash in debug mode, runs fine in release mode?

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, crash

I have this simple loop, running through an array of base class pointers:

```
Object * objects[2];

objects[0] = new GreenObject;
objects[1] = new RedObject;
objects[2] = new BlueObject;


for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    cout << i << " ";
    objects[i]->info();
}
```

Under debug mode, the program crashes on the third iteration of the loop, immediately after outputting `i`, when the `info()` method is invoked. No such thing happens in release mode, it is running as it should. It is not an issue of the object, since it locks up even if I use other derived classes.

GCC 4.4.0 under Windows 7 64bit

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is (and `for` loop) going beyond the end of the array:

```
objects[2] = new BlueObject;
```

causing undefined behaviour. The fact it runs in release is just (un)lucky. A subset of undefined behaviour is it behaves as you expect.

Array indexes run from `0` to `N - 1`, where `N` is the number of elements in the array. In the case of `objects` the valid indexes are `0` and `1` only. Change the declaration of `objects` to:

```
Object * objects[3];
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware the array is shorter than it needs to be, my frustration was with it working in release mode.

Comment: it might have helped if you mention you know it's buggy in the question, saying _"it is running as it should"_ implies you think the code is correct.

Comment: The memory layout of Your program can differ between release and debug settings. As hmjd said, this is completely undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6):

Accessing `objects[2]` is undefined behaviour.

It's a common mistake to expect programming errors to always result in crashes or obvious failures.

Undefined behaviour means anything can happen, including *appearing* to work in some situations.

If you want predictable, repeatable behaviour then you should write correct code.